# How to update state at once on input in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am trying to take input from user and it working but on every input state is update and re render the component . I want to update state at once when user type some query . Now for example if I type 4 characters like ( enta ) then my component re-render 4 types . I want to achieve my goal if for example user type ( enta ) then I don't re-render again and again . I just want to re-render one time . Could someone please help me .

**Code**

```
 <TextInput
        style={styles.inputStyle}
        placeholder="Search medicine and health products"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        onChangeText={(input)=>{
              this.setState({
                subCategoriesShow: true,
                loader: true,
                inputValue: value,
                queries: [],
              });
              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("2@@@@@@@@@ ", this.state.inputValue);
                axios
                  .get(
                    `${config.apiPath}/public/api/search`,
                    {
                      params: {
                        query: this.state.inputValue,
                      },
                    }
                  )
                  .then((res) => {
                    this.setState({
                      queries: res.data,
                      loader: false,
                    });
                  });
              }, 3000);
            }}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
        autoCorrect={false}
      />
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what your intention is. You say you want to re-render just once? When do you expect that one re-render to happen?

Comment: Actually, I am working on user input . when I enter something in TextField and update it state . State is updated but when I try to console then my component is re render again and again

Comment: Well your `onChangeText` function calls `setState` twice, once before and once after your axios call, so you would expect at least two re-renders each time you type a character. I notice you're not using the new `input` value typed by the user here... is that intentional? I would have expected you to update `inputValue` in that first `setState`, since you use it in your API request (instead you're referencing `value` which I don't see defined in this code.)

Answer (score 0):

You can set some character condition or used debounce.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.onChangeTextDelayed = _.debounce(this.onChangeData, 500);
}

 onChangeData = (event) => {
    //call some axios api and set the state.
}

 <TextField
      onChangeText={(event) => {
      this.state.searchText = event
      this.onChangeTextDelayed(event)/>
  }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could look into something along the lines of [lodash.debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce)